# When does frequency distribution matter when using different analysis tools?

Tags: normal-distribution, chi-squared-test

I want to do relationship analysis between different variables from questionnaire results that I've just collected but I've recently learned that you need to make sure certain assumptions are fulfilled before using certain analysis tools. I know with some analysis tools you need to have a normal distribution for your data. In my case I want to use the chi-square test to study relationships between different question responses. But does the frequency distribution of the responses matter if most of my results are nominal/ordinal and I'm using chi-square test for independence?

[image: As you can see for one question/variable, it seems to have a normal distribution, while the other has a lognromal distribution]

Answer (score 0):

The chi-squared test for independence is specifically designed for categorical data. It's specifically for nominal data though it could be used for ordinal data if you are prepared to throw away a lot of information.

In your case both your variables are ordinal apart from the existence of the "I don't know" category that doesn't fit into the ordering.

The chi-square should be okay, though I'd be inclined to test "I don't know" vs "everything else" and then do the ordered categories as ordered (which can be done in several ways).

Comment: This is what I've been wondering about the difference in handling and analyzing nominal vs ordinal data. You mentioned that you'd might want to test "I don't know" (IDK) vs everything else and then do the rest that you mentioned. If I'm doing analysis of ordinal variables, do I need to exclude IDK first? Also, what information am I throwing away if I analyze my data as nominal rather than ordinal? I'm really unfamiliar the difference in analyzing nominal vs ordinal data. I thought you could analyze them the same way.

Comment: If you want to treat it as ordinal, where would "I don't know" fit in the order? You *can* treat your ordinal as nominal (as I mentioned) but it throws away a fair bit of information. There are several options that consider the ordering -- some are discussed on site already. If you search on things that include a term like ordered or ordinal in it you might be able to find some. Perhaps first try a search on *ordinal-ordinal association*.